# add row value to column in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, pivot

I have a table like this:

[image]

now;
I want map row value to column with SELECT statement.
result should be this:
[image]

Comment: From the tags you already know you need to pivot, so what have you tried, and what is your issue/question?

Comment: Your logic is not clear.  For instance, you have two columns of dates and it is not clear which is being used for the result.  The first column of the results is called `id`; that is a column in the original data -- but what happened to the rest of the rows?  Or is this really `personid`?  WHat is `c_date`?  It is not in the original data.

Comment: i need per PERSONID one row that show all ORIGINALDATE for specific REPORTDATE

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
Select * from (select id, person_id, f_device, report_date, originaldate)
pivot
(
 count(*)
 for person_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
);
```

That is you need to aggregate and you will get columns that are in the select statement and for clause. This query will count rows for person_id in (1, 2, 3, 4) and group by the remaining columns internally.

Since your question is not clear if this is not the case please try to improve your question.

Update

```
WITH cte as ( select personid id, reportdate c_date, listagg(originaldate||' ') og FROM my_table GROUP BY personid, reportdate),
cte2 as (SELECT  id, c_date, regexp_substr(og, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 1 ) one,
                                  regexp_substr(og, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 2) two,
                                  regexp_substr(og, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 3 ) three,
                                  regexp_substr(og, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 4 ) four
              from cte)
SELECT * FROM cte2;
```

If you want a distinct personid each row then reportdate needs to be aggregated

```
WITH cte as ( select personid id, max(reportdate ) c_date, listagg(originaldate||' ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY personid ) og FROM my_table GROUP BY personid),
cte2 as (SELECT  id, c_date, regexp_substr(og, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 1 ) one,
                                  regexp_substr(og, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 2) two,
                                  regexp_substr(og, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 3 ) three,
                                  regexp_substr(og, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 4 ) four
              from cte)
SELECT * FROM cte2;
```

Comment: i need per PERSONID one row that show all ORIGINALDATE for specific REPORTDATE

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what is c_date?

Comment: PERSODID in first table  = ID in second table and REPORTDATE in first = c_date in second table

Comment: And reportdate is c_date?

Comment: And one two three are originaldates for a specific person?

Comment: could you please provide me create table and insert statement for your sample data?

Comment: in fact i need a query that convert base table(table one) to second table...second table dose not exist ... i create for show

Comment: I need for first table.

Comment: yes...one tow three is ORGINALDATE  for a specific person

Comment: whats your mean of i need for first table?

Comment: I am saying do you have create table statement and insert statements for sample table on which you need the query?

Comment: first table in my project in our company and i do not access to create table and insert statement

Comment: if you need to statement i write it and send to you

Comment: missing WITHIN keyword

Comment: There was a typo in group by cluase

Comment: I fixed the typo.

Comment: error is still show even after update:(((

Comment: what's the exact error? On my system it's working.

Comment: i changed only my_table name and check column name and run query but it raise this error :ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword
02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"
Error at Line: 45 Column: 89

Comment: line 45 is first line of query

Comment: I guess it's a version issue, what's your database version? check if listagg is supported with your database version.

Comment: i use from SQL DEVELOPER 18.1.0.095.1630 but DataBase itself on remote host.

Comment: SELECT * FROM v$version; run this query

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: WITH cte as ( select personid id, reportdate c_date, listagg(originaldate||' ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY personid, reportdate ) og FROM my_table GROUP BY personid, reportdate),
cte2 as (SELECT  id, c_date, regexp_substr(og, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 1 ) one,
                                  regexp_substr(og, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 2) two,
                                  regexp_substr(og, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 3 ) three,
                                  regexp_substr(og, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 4 ) four
              from cte)
SELECT * FROM cte2; Try this.

Comment: its work!! tank you very much for spend time for me .. but this result contain 6 rows..while i need per personid be one row..as a result we have must two row after run query..like second table:((

Comment: The problem is with the logic, there is c_date and personid you want distinct personid then c_date need to be removed or aggregate. ex 1 date1, 1 date2  and you want one row only for person 1 then there is only one thing we can do with date1 and date2 that is aggregation

Comment: I wnat c_date and personid distinct and every ORGINALDATE set to one,two,three and four. and if ORGINALDATE for one person more than four, dose not matter and if less than four set map null for this cell

Comment: i show in second table in my question. person with id 1 in first table have 4 row with different ORGINALDATE and in second table each ORGINALDATE set to one,two,three and four

Comment: First thing, all your reportdates are distinct. if you want both c_date and personid to be distinct then you may have multiple rows with the same personid because combination of c_date and personid is distinct. You are getting all the 6 rows because all your reportdates are distinct.

Comment: I have modified query in the answer check the last one.

Comment: my priority is all personid are will be distinc

Comment: then use the last modified query in the answer, it will group by with personid so you will get each row with distinct personid and for c_date it choose max.

Comment: c_date unnecessary distinct. i mistake. just personid be distinct

Comment: i use from it but c_date distinct too

Comment: and we need to change regex expression. because i need same value of ORGINALDATE set to one,two...

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: if you pay attention to second table, you will see that values in one, tow, three and four columns, equal with ORGINALDATE column in first table